# React Js : Value / State not getting updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have App.js -

```
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { ActionChangeName } from "./Actions/Action";


function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
            Name
          <input id="txtName" type="text"></input>
          </div>
          <div>
            Age
          <input id="txtAge" type="text"></input>
          </div>
          <div>
          <button onClick={()=>{props.ActionChangeName("Suresh")}}>Change</button>
          </div>
          
          My Name is {props.name}.
          I am {props.age} Years Old !
      
    </div>
  );
}

const mapToProp=(state)=>{
  return{
    ...state,
    name:"Sagar",
    age:"22"
  }
}

const mapToDispatch=(dispatch)=>{
  return {
    ActionChangeName:(name)=>{
      dispatch(ActionChangeName(name));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapToProp,mapToDispatch)(App) ;
```

**Reducer.js -**

```
const iState={
    name :"sagar",
    age:"22"
}

export const reducer=(state=iState,action)=>{
    alert(action.payload);
    return {
        ...state,
        name:action.payload
    }
}
```

**Action.js -**

```
import React from 'react'

export function ActionChangeName(name) {
    return {
            type:"CHANGE_NAME",
            payload :name
    }
}
```

When I am sending "Suresh" via dispatch function , I can see it coming to my reducer via alert.
But I am expecting lable value in App.js to get updated to -

My name is Suresh.

I can see it remaining  - My name is Sagar , which is initial state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you did override your name & age again in `mapStateToProp` function which only state should be returned in the function:

```js
const mapToProp = (state) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    // you would nee to remove this overrides
    // name: "Sagar",
    // age: "22"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there any need of mapToProp function here?

Comment: I removed // name: "Sagar",
    // age: "22"   but initially when page used to get load , I used to show - My name is Sagar .. Now after removing the code it only shows My name is.

Comment: Of course you need, but you should need to list out which state props would be connected. Can you console log what is your state there before return?

Answer (score 0):

**With the updation in @tmhao2005's answer , I updated -**

```
const mapToProp=(state)=>{
  return{
    ...state,
    name:state.name==null?"Sagar":state.name
    //age:"22"
  }
}
```

This started working.
All credit to @tmhao2005 , as without his initial answer wont have been reached to this point.